# Parse error Unexpected token "match" while accessing magento

Tags: magento2, php-7

I am trying to install magento on MAMP server. I have downloaded magento zip file and extracted it to `htdocs` directory.

Installation is successful. However accessing magento throws parse exception

```
Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 34

Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 34

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "match", expecting identifier in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder/Match.php on line 20
```

Command used for installation

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=magento \
--db-password=magento \
--backend-frontname=admin \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1
```

I am using elastic search 7 and it is up and running on port `9200`.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/health?v&pretty'
epoch      timestamp cluster                status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent
1617940234 03:50:34  elasticsearch_dheerajo yellow          1         1      1   1    0    0        1             0                  -                 50.0%
```

Elastic search composer output

```
composer show elasticsearch/elasticsearch
name     : elasticsearch/elasticsearch
descrip. : PHP Client for Elasticsearch
keywords : client, elasticsearch, search
versions : * v7.7.0
type     : library
license  : Apache License 2.0 (Apache-2.0) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/Apache-2.0.html#licenseText
homepage : 
source   : [git] https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php.git 1d90a7ff4fb1936dc4376f09d723af75714f6f05
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/elastic/elasticsearch-php/zipball/1d90a7ff4fb1936dc4376f09d723af75714f6f05 1d90a7ff4fb1936dc4376f09d723af75714f6f05
path     : /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
names    : elasticsearch/elasticsearch

autoload
files
psr-4
Elasticsearch\ => src/Elasticsearch/

requires
ext-json >=1.3.7
ezimuel/ringphp ^1.1.2
php ^7.1
psr/log ~1.0

requires (dev)
cpliakas/git-wrapper ~2.0
doctrine/inflector ^1.3
mockery/mockery ^1.2
phpstan/phpstan ^0.12
phpunit/phpunit ^7.5
squizlabs/php_codesniffer ^3.4
symfony/finder ~4.0
symfony/yaml ~4.0

suggests
ext-curl *
monolog/monolog Allows for client-level logging and tracing
```

`PHP` version is `7.3`

```
php -v
PHP 7.4.12 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2020 13:28:43) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

I am not expert of `PHP` But looks like in `PHP8` Match is a keyword https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php

Any idea on what might be going wrong?

Comment: it looks like you are running this on php8. ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in php8 and as you say Match is a keyword in php 8. Magento is not yet ready for php8. Maybe you have php 7.4 for cli and php 8 for webserver. Just put a `phpinfo()` in a file on the same level as `index.php` and check what that one reports in the browser.

Comment: I have exported 7.4.12 in my bash
which command gives following output
which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin/php

Comment: Despite mentioning php version as 7.4.12 in MAMP configuration. Web server was taking php8 and i could see php-cgi from php8. Looks like MAMP has an issue.